# for each activity in adf is returning {} when lookup activity has data

Tags: azure, foreach, azure-data-factory

I am using a dataset with list of files. Used lookup activity and fed it to the foreach activity.
Lookup output is showing all filenames listed but foreach loop is showing {}
Used @activity('proj1lookup').output.value in the settings of foreach loop

This is the output of lookup , expecting all filenames in foreach loop
{
"count": 5,
"value": [
{
"Files": "ipl 2008.csv"
},
{
"Files": "ipl 2009.csv"
},
{
"Files": "ipl 2010.csv"
},
{
"Files": "ipl 2011.csv"
},
{
"Files": "ipl 2012.csv"
}[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ta5b0.png)
],
"effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime (South India)",
"billingReference": {
"activityType": "PipelineActivity",
"billableDuration": [
{
"meterType": "AzureIR",
"duration": 0.016666666666666666,
"unit": "Hours"
}
],
"totalBillableDuration": [
{
"meterType": "AzureIR",
"duration": 0.016666666666666666,
"unit": "Hours"
}
]
},
"durationInQueue": {
"integrationRuntimeQueue": 0
}
}

Comment: Did you tried tried to access the @item() inside ForEach? what it is resulting?